# Fluent nHibernate mapping - error with unmapped class

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying mapping by code and joining entities. I am using the northwind database to practice and get knowledge about nHibernate. I have been working with this issue for some hours now and have decided to reach out for some help.

I'm trying to map two tables, Orders and Customers from Northwind and join them together with QueryOver. It is a simple console application and my code looks like this.

```
using System;
using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Conformist;
using NHibernate.Mapping;
using NHibernate.Linq;
using NhiberNiteDemo;


namespace NhiberNiteDemo
{
  public class Customers {
    public Customers() { }
    public virtual string Customerid { get; set; }
    public virtual string Companyname { get; set; }
    public virtual string Contactname { get; set; }
    public virtual string Contacttitle { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string Region { get; set; }
    public virtual string Postalcode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual string Fax { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
 }


}
 public class CustomersMap : ClassMapping<Customers> {

    public CustomersMap() {
        Schema("dbo");
        Lazy(true);
        Id(x => x.Customerid, map => map.Generator(Generators.Assigned));
        Property(x => x.Companyname, map => map.NotNullable(true));
        Property(x => x.Contactname);
        Property(x => x.Contacttitle);
        Property(x => x.Address);
        Property(x => x.City);
        Property(x => x.Region);
        Property(x => x.Postalcode);
        Property(x => x.Country);
        Property(x => x.Phone);
        Property(x => x.Fax);
    //  Bag(x => x.Customercustomerdemo, colmap =>  { colmap.Key(x =>       x.Column("CustomerID")); colmap.Inverse(true); }, map => { map.OneToMany(); });
        Set(x => x.Orders, colmap =>  { colmap.Key(x => x.Column("CustomerID")); colmap.Inverse(true); }, map => { map.OneToMany();  });
    }
}
public class Order
{
  public Order() { }
  public virtual int Orderid { get; set; }
  public virtual ISet<Customers> customers { get; set; }
  // public virtual Employees Employees { get; set; }
  //public virtual Shippers Shippers { get; set; }
 public virtual DateTime Orderdate { get; set; }
 public virtual DateTime Requireddate { get; set; }
 public virtual DateTime Shippeddate { get; set; }
 public virtual decimal Freight { get; set; }
 public virtual string Shipname { get; set; }
 public virtual string Shipaddress { get; set; }
 public virtual string Shipcity { get; set; }
 public virtual string Shipregion { get; set; }
 public virtual string Shippostalcode { get; set; }
 public virtual string Shipcountry { get; set; }
}




public class OrdersMap : ClassMapping<Order>
{

 public OrdersMap()
 {
     Schema("dbo");
     Lazy(true);
     Id(x => x.Orderid, map => map.Generator(Generators.Identity));
     Property(x => x.Orderdate);
     Property(x => x.Requireddate);
     Property(x => x.Shippeddate);
     Property(x => x.Freight);
     Property(x => x.Shipname);
     Property(x => x.Shipaddress);
     Property(x => x.Shipcity);
     Property(x => x.Shipregion);
     Property(x => x.Shippostalcode);
     Property(x => x.Shipcountry);
     ManyToOne(x => x.customers, map =>
     {
         map.Column("CustomerID");
         map.NotNullable(true);
         map.Cascade(Cascade.None);
     });
/*
     ManyToOne(x => x.Employees, map =>
     {
         map.Column("EmployeeID");
         map.PropertyRef("Employeeid");
         map.NotNullable(true);
         map.Cascade(Cascade.None);
     });
  */
     /*
     ManyToOne(x => x.Shippers, map =>
     {
         map.Column("ShipVia");
         map.NotNullable(true);
         map.Cascade(Cascade.None);
     });
       */
    // Set(x => x.OrderDetails, colmap => { colmap.Key(x =>    x.Column("OrderID")); colmap.Inverse(true); }, map => { map.OneToMany(); });
 }
}


 public class Program
{
    private static Lazy<ISessionFactory> factory = new  Lazy<ISessionFactory>(GetSessionFactory, System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       // using (ISession session = OpenSession())
        {
        //    IList<Customers> Customers = session.Query<Customers>().Where(p => p.Customerid == "ALFKI").ToList();
            //IList<Pet> pets = query.List<Pet>();
        //    // Console.Out.WriteLine("pets.Count = " + pets.Count);
       //     Customers.ToList().ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.Contactname));
       //     Console.Read();
        }
        Testhib();

    }

    public static void Testhib()
    {
        ISession session = OpenSession();
        session.QueryOver<Order>()
            .JoinQueryOver<Customers>(p => p.customers).Where(k => k.Customerid == "ALFKI");


        //Console.WriteLine("Jow Jow");
        // Console.Read();

    }


    private static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return factory.Value.GetCurrentSession();
    }

    private static ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory()
    {
        //NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration
        var c = new Configuration();
        //c.Configure();
        c.DataBaseIntegration(db =>
        {
            db.ConnectionString = "Server=\"nsure-shj\";database=NORTHWND;Integrated Security=SSPI";
            db.Dialect<NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect>();

        });
        //c.Configure("c:\XML.xml");

        ModelMapper maps = new ModelMapper();
       // maps.AddMapping<CustomersMap>();
        maps.AddMappings(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes());

        c.AddMapping(maps.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities());
        c.CurrentSessionContext<NHibernate.Context.ThreadLocalSessionContext>();
        //c.Configure().Configure();
        var sessionFac = c.BuildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFac;

        //return sessionFac.GetCurrentSession();

    }



}
```

I have figured out that i can map all my classmaps by this

```
maps.AddMappings(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes());
```

But when when I am running this code it throws an exception from the BuildSessionFactory method with following message:

```
An association from the table Order refers to an unmapped class:   System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[[NhiberNiteDemo.Customers, NhiberNiteDemo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

Can anyone help determine the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code snippet - this looks like a namespace issue. You have enclosed only the Customers class in the namespace `NhiberNiteDemo` try moving that the closing `}` for the namespace to encapsulate all of your code above.

If that doesn't solve the issue you need to make sure that your mappings are being loaded. Try removing the `Customers` property from your `Order` entity and then alter the query so that it is a straightforward select on the `Orders` entity and see if it works without issue. This will determine whether the mappings have loaded correctly.